# Export map differs from layout

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-pro, export, layouts

I can't get my exported map to show my raster layers as they appear in the layout.  Specifically, my layout includes four data frames, each with its own raster showing areas stippled with colored pixels, but the exported map makes it look as though much more of the area is colored.  I've tried this in both ArcMap 10.6 and ArcGIS Pro 2.1.2 and have tried exporting in every format and at nearly ever setting (even ridiculously high dpi) but can't seem to achieve a WYSIWYG.  C and D seem okay, but A and B (much more diffuse) renders very wrong and certainly doesn't accurately portray the data.

[image]

These are simply rasters of unsuitable/suitable (0/1).  DRA is not checked.  I've tried every color combination (light/dark, dark/light), tried adjusting every setting under Image Analysis (contrast, brightness, etc.) and all the resampling methods (the default being nearest neighbor).  Of note, setting resample = majority makes for much fewer colored areas (=1) appearing on the layout, but this doesn't seem to cause any change in the exported map.  Deleting the ovr files (as suggested by @johns) made no discernible difference. It is still a poor representation of the data and what I see in the layout.  Looking at the exported B above, most think that 75-85% of the area =1, when in fact it is only 38%.

Comment: Have you tried doing this using ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: @PolyGeo I'm not as familiar with ArcGIS Pro, so I was hoping to avoid trying that.  Map export is that much different, better than ArcMap?

Comment: My understanding is that the graphics engine was overhauled between ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro so any particular issue should stand a good chance of having been addressed but that cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: @PolyGeo I tried this through ArcGIS Pro, but the output was identical to ArcMap.  Zooming in, I can see that the colored vs. white pixels are the same in the layout as the exported map.  But at full size, they look very different.

Comment: You may want to switch this question to ArcGIS Pro or to open an ArcGIS Pro equivalent to it. Be sure to keep editing rather than commenting any time you have new information to add.

Comment: You might check your raster symbology properties; the exported tifs may be coming in with a different stretch or other values.  If they didn't look good up close I'd also suggest looking at the output image quality setting but if they are then another check if you have built pyramids, is to delete any ovr files since that may cause issues at the full display that you wouldn't see up close.